# CICS/COBOL Abend ASRA in debugger only

Tags: debugging, cobol, mainframe, cics

I have an issue I don't seem to find a solution for. 
One of the transactions gives ABEND ASRA when used in debug mode. 
When I compile the Cobol program without debug option and run the program, it works fine.

The error looks like this one (quite exactly like this), only I am using Cobol V4:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM96501

Now the question would be: why is it abending in debugger and not without debugger? 
I am using the CICS debugger (DTCN transaction), the program starts normally, I can do steps with F2 and all this, then at some location is abends. 
Please note that it is extremely difficult to say where it abends as the program is really big.

This happens only to this program at the moment, others are running fine with debugger. I placed a breakpoint before my modifications, the abend occurs in some other area.

Another weird thing is that this Abend is not consistent, If I do a big portion of the code with small steps (F2 and small breakpoints), sometimes it executes without abend until the end.

Due to the nature of the issue, I can not post much information.
I was hoping you encountered similar issues and you can tell me where to look for.

Thank you!

Comment: I managed to find the problematic call:
Call 'DFHEI1' using by content x'0204ff000713120e15100f0d5400   
'0000000000000000f3f5f0f5f9404040' end-call.This is a CICS EXEC statement in the program. If I pass this area with step-by-step (F2), the abend is not given, the program ends normally.

Comment: You need to look at the generated code (OPTION LIST,NOOFFSET) and verify that that value has not been clobbered. Do you have to recompile to use DTCN? Sometimes, rarely, something is being overwritten which does not cause an immediate problem. Change the code generated, and now something is overwritten which does cause an immediate problem. Sometimes.

Comment: I recompile with debugger option to use DTCN. 
I will compare the debugger code with the standard code later to see if there are any major differences.

Comment: I logged a ticket to our specialist team to investigate this, I just can't find anything by myself. I will post the solution if they can give me one.

Comment: I received the response from our specialist team. The issue was solved by deleting my debug tool profile form the system and then login to the debugger (DTCN) again so it creates a new profile (the profile was 3 files: TOOLTEMP.PDTOOLS.{userid}.DBGTOOL.* ). After this the issue was gone. I asked the guys how this happened, they told me this was because I had modified the program between 2 debugging sessions without closing CICS. This was a disfunction that can be avoided by closing CICS while we compile programs used in it (not sure about why exactly.... neither are they).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was solved by deleting my debug tool profile form the system and then login to the debugger (DTCN) again so it creates a new profile (the profile was 3 files: TOOLTEMP.PDTOOLS.{userid}.DBGTOOL.* ). After this the issue was gone. I asked the guys how this happened, they told me this was because I had modified the program between 2 debugging sessions without closing CICS. This was a disfunction that can be avoided by closing CICS while we compile programs used in it (not sure about why exactly.... neither are they).
Hope this helps if you face a similar issue with DTCN debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've never heard of the need to close CICS to do a compile. There is a need to tell the running CICS that you have a "new" program, and perhaps some version of that would suffice.

Comment: I agree, and I did just that (CEMT SET PROG() NEWCOPY). Apparently something went wrong in this case, altough we are not closing CICS to compile a new program and then CEMT it. Unfortunately the support team can't say for sure what happened, they don't have time to investigate once it's solved.